# How to auto redeploy app resources with Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, ide

I have the web app that was build with maven, now i'm learning gradle and want to know is there a way for auto redeploy of resources (class files, js, css, jsp's etc.) with gradle ?

With the help of IDE it was easy enough, but now i'm using cargo plugin and run gradle task from command line so IDE can't help here.

Is there any simplification, so I wont need to stop tomcat and run task again every time ?

Comment: Show your current build.gradle, what plugins are you already using? The war plugin and war task should build a war already will all required dependencies and resources.

Comment: @RaGe i do not have a problem building a war. the question is about how to update that war automatically. IDEA for example has feature called `war exploded` as i remember. so i deploy war on locale tomcat, made a change in some class(js, css, whatever) and IDE automatically detects this and reloads war with those changes. is there a way to do it with Gradle ?

Comment: Have you looked at gradle tomcat plugin? (As opposed to cargo plugin)

Comment: @RaGe yes, but it runs an embedded tomcat